# How can I reverse list and replace all the specified values with other value?

Tags: prolog

Imagine that we have a list: `[1,2,2,3,4]`. The problem can be splitted into two parts:

- Reverse the list (we should receive `[4,3,2,2,1]`)
- Replace, e.g. all `2` with `100`, so we should receive `[4,3,100,100,1]`

It's easy to reverse the list, here's a working code:

```
simple_reverse(List, Rev) :-
        simple_reverse(List, Rev, []).

simple_reverse([], L, L).
simple_reverse([H|T], L, SoFar) :-
        simple_reverse(T, L, [H|SoFar]).
```

But I have some troubles with replacing the elements. I have tried the following approach:

```
reverse(a, b, List, Rev) :-
        reverse(a, b, List, Rev, []).

reverse(a, b, [], L, L).

reverse(a, b, [H|T], L, SoFar) :-
        reverse(a, b, T, L, [H|SoFar]).

reverse(a, b, [a|T], L, SoFar) :-
        reverse(a, b, T, L, [b|SoFar]).
```

What is the problem? By the way, I'm using https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ to run the code.

Comment: You know `a` and `b` aren't variables, right? Anyway, assuming you fix that, `reverse(a, b, [H|T], L, SoFar) :-
        reverse(a, b, T, L, [H|SoFar]).` doesn't ensure that `H` and `a` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just `a`,`b` (which are atoms) you need to place variables in `reverse/4` and `reverse/5` predicates:

```
reverse(A, B, List, Rev) :-
        reverse(A, B, List, Rev, []).

reverse(_, _, [], L, L).

reverse(A, B, [H|T], L, SoFar) :-
        dif(A,H),              %case where H is not A so we skip it
        reverse(A, B, T, L, [H|SoFar]).

reverse(A, B, [A|T], L, SoFar) :-
        reverse(A, B, T, L, [B|SoFar]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foldl in conjonction with library(lambda) :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
my_reverse(L, A, B, R) :-
    foldl([A,B] +\X^Y^Z^(dif(X, A) -> Z = [X |Y]; Z = [B|Y]), L, [],R).
```

example :

```
?- my_reverse([1,2,2,3,4], 2, 100, R).
R = [4, 3, 100, 100, 1].
```